# Active Directory - Account exists but cannot find it to remove it

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I'm trying to add an AD Managed Service Account and my first attempt was as follows:

```
New-ADServiceAccount -DNSHostName VM-Backup-Service -Name "VM Backup" -samAccountName VM_Backup -Path "OU=AD_Managed_Service_Accounts,DC=company,DC=local"
```

This command basically hung, I think because I pointed DNSHostName to something non-existent because I didn't do enough reading. I then tried to correct it and point it at the master DC using it's FQDN:

```
New-ADServiceAccount -DNSHostName AUDC.company.local -Name "VM Backup" -SamAccountName VM_Backup -Path "OU=AD_Managed_Service_Accounts,DC=company,DC=local"
```

The problem I have now is that AD says the account already exists:

```
New-ADServiceAccount : The specified account already exists
```

Which would be no big problem, if I could actually find said account in order to remove it before re-adding it correctly. I've tried tracking it down with:

```
Get-ADServiceAccount -filter 'samAccountName -like "*VM_Backup*"'
Get-ADUser -filter 'samAccountName -like "*VM_Backup*"'
```

And the following returns nothing, which implies there are no Service Accounts in the domain?

```
Get-ADServiceAccount -filter *
```

If anyone has suggestions for ways to track it down, it would be much appreciated. The only hints I have is that I know I specified the samAccountName in the commands above, and the snippet of the **CN=VM Backup** that is returned when it says the account already exists:

```
New-ADServiceAccount : The specified account already exists
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ADServiceAccount -DNSHostName yyy-server-001.companydomain.local  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (CN=VM Backup,OU...ompany,DC=local:String) [New-ADServiceAccount], ADIde
   ntityAlreadyExistsException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1316,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADServiceAcc
   ount
```

Comment: Well, it answer you, ResourceExists: (CN=VM Backup,OU...ompany,DC=local:String), the **...** is in fact the location to look for.

Comment: Have you tried finding the account through the "Active Directory Users and Computers" control panel applet?

Comment: Your track down attempt is really with an underscore between VM and Backup while the attempt to recreate has a space between?

Comment: @MaxVernon
Yes I have, and I can see the OU I expect it to be in based on the path, and there is nothing there even after some refreshes. I also checked the generic 'Managed Service Accounts' container and it hasn't showed up in there either.
Using find on the domain within UAC (searching users or searching computers) also fails to locate it.

Comment: @LotPings
The distinction between VM_Backup and "VM Backup" is the parameter used when creating it (-samAccountName and -Name respectively). As far as I can tell, I should be able to find both of those, but can't find either.

Comment: @yagmoth555
I would concur. And It's not there based on any means of searching or listing that I'm familiar with in AD. Hence the question basically.

Comment: @Chris it should be there, its the location of the object, like if in OU test, it would be wrote there, no other DC not in sync ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 I agree! There is only one DC in this environment (which is a separate problem to solve). It's as though it's written some of the information to AD, but not all the required entries in order to be able to properly establish the complete hierarchy.

Comment: Using the $Error objects properties of Category, Reason and TargetName (i.e $Error[0].CategoryInfo.Category) helped get around the truncated error output to confirm the path AD thinks it lives on, starting from the CN=VM Backup,OU=......

I've navigated, searched, hunted and generally tried to locate something anything based on the path or CN and it's all coming up blank. I'm going to take the DC offline and run esenutl and/or ntdsutil for integrity and semantic analysis (and possibly recovery) and see if the problems goes away after that. I'm all out of other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe there were multiple parts to solving this:

1. It appears that I needed to have the DC in the default "Domain Controllers" OU (not in a sub/child OU, as per this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3bbc81de-83fb-4c40-8a03-e03ede1a458b/group-managed-service-accounts-causing-delays-freezes-lock-ups-and-service-outages?forum=winserverDS). Supposedly Microsoft have resolved that issue (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3094486), so maybe only point 2 below is relevant, but I did both so I figured I would mention it here.
2. The DC had only recently been rebuilt (following an AD corruption). Turns it it allows time for convergence between DC's before allowing service accounts to be created (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/82617035-254f-4078-baa2-7b46abb9bb71/newadserviceaccount-key-does-not-exist?forum=winserver8gen). As there was only one DC in this environment, convergence was not an issue, so I ran the command suggested in the article (as per below). Either this step alone, or in concert with step 1, was sufficient to resolve the issue. Why AD thought the object existed prior to these steps rather than just rejecting the command outright, I have no clue.

   **Add-KdsRootKey –EffectiveTime ((get-date).addhours(-10))**